# How to count random rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem trying to come out with a solution for my job.

I work at a warehouse and we work on containers. Each containers has X amount of boxes and X amount of paperwork for the boxes. We are also given a due date.

I wanted to use some kind of algorithm or formulas but I don't know how to use it of any kind.

Lets say i have 1000 containers and 700,000 boxes&28,000 Paper Work to be done in the next 7 days with 2 different shifts. For those containers I already have a list of the 1,000 of what needs to be done, but i want to do it quickly with excel to distribute the work based on categories. In those 1000, I also have a due date. So lets say I want to do 72 Containers per shift (144 for 1 day). I also want to do 50,000 boxes each shift with 2000 paper work also each shift.

My priorities is first Due Date, if a container is getting close to current date, that takes priority(lets say within 1 day). Next if i want to do 50,000 boxes and 2000 paper work per shift, i want to insert that into a cell and excel will automatically select the best 72 containers per shift that prioritizes due date(doesn't matter how many boxes or papers if it is within 1 day)and then chooses what ever best containers that will equal out to 50,000 boxes and 2,000 papers. Each container and its information in written per row with the columns having headers. I want it to be done this way so that i don't manually count each container so that i can best distribute the same amount of work to each shift. This way my 1 hour process can be done in 5 minutes.

I don't know if i am asking too much but i just need a sample to then test it on a file.

Sorry for providing the wrong information right away. I've included a sample of what I am trying to achieve.
Instead of 72 containers, with the example I lowered it 11 per shift but the boxes and paper count didn't change.

[Container List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfwVJ.png)

What this shows is that the yellow highlighted were selected because of due date being very close to current date. Orange highlight were selected to complete the 11 container count goal while being as close as possible to 50k boxes and 2k load slips. Then were sorted for email purposes, the other 11 were also already selected for the 2nd shift when they come in keeping in mind of the same goal as 1st shift. Any left containers are going to ignored at least till the next day.
Is this possible or am I thinking too far ahead of myself.

Comment: Can you show some sample data in your table?

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of hard work to read. I could barely do that. And I know I don't understand what you're asking for. So it's impossible to come up with an answer. Please have a rethink about [ask] and see if you can break this down in to simple steps with an explanation for each step. Give us sample input data and then gives us the results you expect to see for that data. Then we might have a hope of being able to help.

Comment: A small addition to @enigmativity; asking your questions in a pure-word way to a number-oriented community is not a very good idea IMHO. I am sure this long wordy story can be much better told using tables, numbers, sample desired outputs etc. And also I may suggest you take your time to see the pages on how to create a [mcve].